# How create an Interactive map on wordpress/elementor page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I am on a project that I have a section where there is an interactive map as the image below, I am looking for a plugin or somehow I can build this. Basically, when you hover the points on the map it will change the point colour and show on the left side the location information.

[image]

If someone knows some plugin that I can build something similar or how I can build that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet with OpenStreetMap Data.

Bit of simple Javascript and HTML

https://leafletjs.com/